# Checklist for Data Communication Review in ERP Solution

Tags: cryptography, key-management

I am looking out for a checklist for data communication review within ERP application.

I understand some of the checks would be related to digital signature, TLS/SSL use, Key Life Cycle management etc. Can you please point me to the baseline checks to provide maximum coverage for the review. The prime focus of review is to cover data in transit.